# Another way of saying "hanging by a thread"

Tags: word-usage

Instead of using "Hanging by a thread" in the context of someone walking endlessly in the desert and being barely able to continue, what is a better choice of phrase?

Comment: Well, if the guy is *hanging by a thread*, then he's clearly also *at the end of his rope*.

Comment: What about _dying of thirst_? (I think your question could be improved if you made an edit, and explained why you don't like _hanging by a thread_. Otherwise, this becomes a guessing game as we all try to figure out which direction you'd like to go with this. What's constitutes "better" here? Less trite? More literally accurate? More precarious?)

Comment: An engine with practically no fuel left is "running on fumes", this could be extended to the "mortal flesh engine" but may evoke a connotation of drugs use with some, I guess. "Running on willpower alone" maybe?

Comment: On his last legs ...?

Comment: Good for you for rejecting _hanging by a thread_. Except where the reference to the Sword of Damocles is fully intended, _hanging by a thread_ is hackneyed, nearly moribund. (And there's a word for you!) Metaphorically, the person could be said to be fading (with each step), faltering, withering, ebbing (too watery?), wasting, languishing, vanishing, and on and on.

Alternatively, one might focus on the difficult but determined movement forward toward (inevitable?) extinction: staggering, stumbling, inching, tottering, faltering, reeling on toward a close-by grave in the sand.

Comment: You can always, of course, make direct reference to the [Sword of Damocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damocles#Sword_of_Damocles) hanging over you, but that's still employing the same metaphor.

Comment: @Dan Brown Or you could say he was at the end of his tether.

Answer (score 0):

As Lady Galadriel so eloquently stated: The quest [of the Fellowship] *stands on the edge of a knife*.

Comment: I don't know, I think that metaphor indicates the quest could go *either way* with the slightest change of fortune. Whereas the man marooned in the desert is doomed (or at least the odds lean much more in that direction).

Comment: Well, if you recall the moment in the movie, you will see that it the expression is not intended to be neutral, but negative, like in the OP's example :)

Comment: Fair enough. +1.

Comment: Yes, my take on that scene / usage was that the only "good" way to go is farther along the edge; moving to either side involves a precipitous fall.  And the knife isn't exactly helping you stay on its edge, either.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of common expressions to describe someone whose mortality is "hanging by a thread". Off the top of my head:

Barely clinging to life,
Barely holding on,
On his/her last legs,
Running out of time...

Or, if you're writing fiction, consider describing the actual symptoms that one might experience when suffering and/or dying in the desert rather than simply stating outright that he/she is not doing so well: show; don't tell.

Think about how dry and sandpapery someone's tongue might feel, how each breath made his/her lungs burn, how tired eyes struggled to cope with being blasted by sand and so on.

Answer (score 0):

["Hanging on by the skin of one's teeth"](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/11/popular-idioms-explained/) is a biblical reference:

> My bone cleaveth to my skin and to my flesh, and I am escaped with the skin of my teeth (Job 19:20).

The allusion is to narrowness.

Comment: Or a little less dramatically, hanging on by his fingernails.